# ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman

I'm trying to make a web api using the new .NET Core. But having some trouble using the the `[HttpPost]`. When I use postman, it doesn't return anything. Also when I put a breakpoint on the return line it's never hit.

This is my method in the controller:

```
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<string> Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

The GET method is working:

```
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

It returns a Json value and when I place a breakpoint it hits.

I think I have to add something somewhere else to map the post to this method, but I can't figure out what.

### Update: The post request

This is the Post code generated in Postman:

```
POST /api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60228
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 295f7c89-f5a8-d6cd-d679-ae907b010550

firstName:jantje
```

Comment: please show us the Post request

Comment: I've added the post request to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to post JSON data to your controller action and use a model class to bind the values. I assume the simple string cannot be parsed by the JSON or XML formatters that are used by ASP.NET Core by default.

So this will probably work:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]DataModel model)
{
    return Ok();
}

public class DataModel {
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

with this JSON data

```
{
    firstName: "jantje"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself in the same situation and the reason was that i send text/plain request instead of application/json request.

After this change I was able to send a simple string to the HttpPost action. Before the change no breakpoint was hit too.

I've tried it with ValuesController from the WebAPI example and it runs too.