# .NET Core API - Postman returning error on POST request

Tags: c#, .net, api, postman, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm learning .NET Core API Web from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc

As in the tutorial says, I have a Model called TodoItems

I can send GET requests, but I cannot send any POST request to create a TodoItem to my API Web (please head to the **"Use Postman to send a Create request"** section from the tutorial link above)

I have done exactly as the tutorial, but I got the **Unexpected "<"** error on Postman on POST request [image]

Please help.

Comment: Are there any errors logged on the server?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, I've posted an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720818/asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: We would have to see the code you've created to be able to help. That error would usually indicate that you have a < typo somewhere in the code, though the problem may be more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved.

I didn't specify the HttpPut method for the Update function, and the HttpDelete method for the Delete function